# can't access value through input using button

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some exercises and come across where I can't pass the value from the input box to a function inside a script, I don't really know what I have done wrong, I tried different things but didn't really work out. How can I make it work? I want to able to enter a number then press a button so that it prints pyramid according to given number, here is my code :

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let aantalLijnen = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);
  document.getElementById("button").onclick = stars();
  function stars() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= aantalLijnen; i++) {
      var row = '';
      for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        row += '*';
      }
      console.log(row);
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<p>Give a number betweeen 2 and 10
  <input type="number" id='number'>
  <button id="button">Click</button></p>
```

Comment: `window.onload = function() {` is unnecessary. `defer` your script or simply place it right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `stars()` and assigning the result to the `onclick` handler.

You need to pass the function itself...

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = stars;
```

---

Or just create an anonymous function directly...

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
   ...
}
```

---

As pointed out by @j08691, you are setting the value of `aantalLijnen` on the page load.

Instead you want to get the value at the time the function runs, so you need to move it into the function itself...

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
    let aantalLijnen = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);
    for (var i = 1; i <= aantalLijnen; i++) {
      var row = '';
      for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        row += '*';
      }
      console.log(row);
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<p>Give a number betweeen 2 and 10
  <input type="number" id='number'>
  <button id="button">Click</button></p>
```

Comment: Should also move the `let` inside the function otherwise it's just getting the value once when the doc loads

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the value from input every time you click on the button

```
 window.onload = function () {
            const numberElem = document.getElementById('number');
            document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', stars);
            function stars() {
                let aantalLijnen = parseInt(numberElem.value);
                for (var i = 1; i <= aantalLijnen; i++) {
                    var row = '';
                    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                        row += '*';
                    }
                    console.log(row);
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides what already said by others

- Don't use `onclick` handlers. Stick to cumulative listeners with `addEventListener`
- You could use [String.prototype.repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat);
- Defer your script or place it right before the closing `</body>` tag
- Learn the difference between `let` and `const`

```js
function stars() {
  const num = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
  if (num < 2 || num > 10) return console.log("Use from 2 to 10 inclusive");
  const row = '*'.repeat(num);
  console.log(row)
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', stars);
```

```html
Give a number betweeen 2 and 10
<input type="number" id='number'>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```